# Is there a case for a String.IsNullOrEmpty operator?

Tags: c#

`String.IsNullOrEmpty()` appears to be an extremely well used method and I find myself wishing there were some shorthand for it. Something like `???` as it would be used in a similar context to the null coalesce operator but be extended to test for empty as well as null strings. I.e.

```
 string text = something.SomeText ??? "Not provided";
```

What would be your opinions on this? Would it unnecessarily bloat the language? Would it open the floodgates for other mid-level operations to be granted such deep integration with the compiler? Or would it be a useful addition for the language.

Comment: Not opposed the idea, but dread the thought of ?, ??, ???, ????, ?????, ??????, ??????? etc

Comment: what does it achieve? the purpose of a language is not to combine every statement onto a single line....or is it?  Imagine single line programs....

Comment: The C# language has plenty of special `String` knowledge (look at how `"string" + "concatenation" + "works"`)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat There are a lot of single line programs: in F# :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I think compactness is actually useful as long as it's not (too) confusing. Not sure about this particular example though.

Comment: @onof:  hmmm, I really want to sign up to support those....

Comment: A developer here wrote a *handy* `MyCompareTo` extension method that first checked to see was the `this` parameter null. I was forced to channel dogbert, **Out, out, you demons of stupidity!!**

Comment: @DrJokepu: Regular expressions can be compact: aren't they fun to support!

Comment: Also, how about the new String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()? Will that be "????"

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Hence I said "as long as it's not (too) confusing"

Comment: @ DrJokepu: confusing is relative.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat I agree with you (compactness is not the purpose of a language). I was just kidding F#

Comment: @Mitch: No, compactness is not the purpose of the language. But the main case here is not compactness, but reducing repetition and making the writing of code more efficient for common tasks.

Comment: @Binary Worrier - in point of fact, the `this` parameter in extension methods CAN be null.

Comment: Intellisense reduces the keystrokes for me for this method to just a couple. Why not rely on that and let the code remain readable?

Comment: @Joel Mueller: Yes, they **can** be null, but that doesn't mean that you *should* use them this way. Calling any method (including an extension method) on a `null` object reference is just frackin *wrong*. The following code should provoke a **Seriously WTF** reaction from *everyone* `if(myObj == null && !myObj.MyMethod(1)`. Anyone that would write this deserves a whack with a stout stick and **Out, out, you demons of stupidity!!** NB: Not for *thinking* the `this` parameter can be `null`, but for allowing it to be null!

Comment: @Binary Worrier - I still fail to see why defensive coding by checking for null in case someone screwed up somewhere else is enough to invoke the spirit of Dogbert.

Comment: @Joel Mueller: Joel, I'm all for defensive coding, therefore one should check the `this` parameter of an extension method, and throw if it's null. I shall try to explain more clearly why Dogbert applies here. Imagine the days before extension methods, if you even glanced at this code you'd *know* something was very wrong `if(myObj == null && !myObj.MyMethod(1))` What the frack, `myObj` is null and you're going to call `MyMethod` on it? Before extension methods that's an **epic fail**. Now we have extension methods, and we *can* do it, but that doesn't mean we should do it (continued)

Comment: (resumed). That you can write code that looks like a method call on a null object is - to my mind - just plain wrong. At the very least it's a code smell.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Phil Haack [blogged about this](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/06/16/null-or-empty-coalescing.aspx) a while ago. Basically, he suggests an extension method on `string` that lets you do

```
var text = someString.AsNullIfEmpty() ?? "Not provided.";
```

The extension method is very simple:

```
public static string AsNullIfEmpty(this string str)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? str : null;
}
```

He also suggests a version checking for whitespace instead of just empty with the `string.IsNullOrWhitespace()` method from .NET 4, as well as similar extensions for the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

He also talks about introducing new operators such as `???` for this, but concludes that it would be more confusing than helpful - after all, introducing these extension methods you can do the same thing, but it's more readable, and it's using shorthand syntax that "everybody already knows".

Comment: The problem is, as developers, we get hung up on these geeky pursuits. Ask yourself, "will this help the users of this software", "will this make a better bottom line for the company that uses this software"???

Comment: if you want to introduce new extension method, maybe this version will express intensions more clear
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ValueOrDefault(this string value, string defaultValue)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? defaultValue : value;
    }
}

Comment: @Mitch: The main reason to introduce these extension methods is not (only) to make this code look nice - it is also to reduce code repetition. How many times have you found yourself wanting to check a string for `null`, empty or whitespace, and provide a default value if needed? I do that all the time. And with these extension methods, I *save time when writing software*, which benefits (at least) the company I write software for.

Comment: @desco: Now that I think about it, using the ternary operator does make sense. (I updated my post to reflect this.) However, your extension method will never return null - there might be other cases than providing default values for returning null on empty or whitespace, in which case this extension already has it covered. That said, yours is a good complement to this if you think it makes your code more readable and maintainable. You could in fact even use "my" extension in the implementation of yours =)

Comment: @Tomas Lycken: Source extension method is intended to be used in pair with ?? operator and together this couple expresses the same thing as my one method: check string and return either itself or some default value.

Comment: I think it's a nice idea to use utility/extension methods for tasks such as these.  In this case, I think I might also like to have an `IfNullOrEmpty(this string input, string @default)` extension method, so that I could call it like this:
`var text = someString.IfNullOrEmpty("Not provided.");`

It would be similar to the IsNull function in SQL Server.

Using this 'AsNullIfEmpty' extension method in conjunction with the ?? operator just seems a little klunky to me.

Comment: @Dr. Wily's Apprentice: Yes, that is exactly what desco is suggesting too, only more readable =) And I'm definitely not against having that extension as well - I just think being able to treat empty/whitespace strings as null might have more applications than coalescing a default value. For example, you might want to pass a string or null to another method; in that case, I think `someString.IfNullOrEmpty(null)` looks a little clunky. But there's nothing that prevents us from having both ;)

Comment: @desco, see my last comment to Dr Wily's Apprentice.

Comment: That looks like an excellent technique and pretty much negates my question! :)

Answer (score 6):

Phil Haack talks about this exact operation on his blog. You should check out his article [`Null Or Empty Coalescing`](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/06/16/null-or-empty-coalescing.aspx).

Special purpose operators like `???` are a slippery slope. Why stop there - why not introduce a "*null or empty or whitespace*" operator: `????`. Phil talks about this, actually, in his article. His overall conclusion is that such operators would be more confusing than helpfull.

Ultimately you could take many different operations an invent operators to represent them - unfortunately, that would likely destroy the readability of the language.

Comment: Sigh... just because I wanted to type out a couple of examples, you beat me by less than a minute...! ;)

Comment: @Tomas: It hasn't seemed to hurt your score on this question. Nice job.